# Bash script - find directory, and do something in it. Or find a file, and do something with it

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, bash, terminal

This is what I have so far:

```
for f in 'svn ls repository_dir'; 
do 
svn checkout repository_dir/$f/trunk/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/needed_dir 
done
```

This works great for the projects (100's of them) that have the needed_dir in the correct place. But some projects ($f) have their directory structure a little different. So "needed_dir" might be in a different location.

**In the do loop**, how can I tell my bash script to:

"Find "needed_dir". If found, check it out."

Or

"Find "needed_file.txt". If found, check it out."

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 1):

This will probably be easiest with [find](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find).

To execute `svn checkout` or every directory named `needed_dir` in the directory tree of `repository_dir/$f/trunk`, use this command:

```
find repository_dir/$f/trunk/ -type d -name needed_dir -exec svn checkout {} \;
```

Find substitutes `{}` with the name of the found directory.

The switch `-type d` only finds directories, while `-type f` finds only files.

Comment: For some reason when I press [Enter] on the command in the terminal, it doesn't finish. I get the ">" in the terminal, as if it's waiting for more. My command is "for f in `svn ls https://repository_dir/`; do find https://repository_dir/$f/trunk/ -type d -name needed_dir -exec svn checkout {} \; done" Any ideas?

Comment: @user1776193: You missed one `;`. Should be: ``for f in `svn ls https://repository_dir/`; do find repository_dir/$f/trunk -type d -name needed_dir -exec svn checkout {} \;; done``

Comment: @clarkw when I add the extra 

    ;

at the end, it gives me the error: 

    -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `done'

Comment: @user1776193: As it said it's syntax error so try to fix it yourself. It's easy.

Comment: I see no reason why the command as it is wouldn't work. Could you copy and paste the actual command you're using?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I don't have enough reputation to comment, so I have to create a new answer.

The `find` command is not going to work here because it can only search a directory on disk.  (So it would work only if you first svn checkout the entirety of "repository_dir".)

See [the following link on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704901/search-in-svn-repository-for-a-file-name) for a similar question.  Something similar to the answer given there is more appropriate:

```
for f in 'svn ls -R repository_dir | grep "needed_dir"'; 
do 
svn checkout repository_dir/$f
done
```

The -R option to svn makes svn list everything at URL recursively.  Grep searches for the directory you need.

For what it is worth, you can make this somewhat more terse by using the `xargs` command instead of a for loop.

```
svn list -R <URL> | grep "needed_dir" | xargs --max-args=1 -I'{}' svn co <URL>'{}'
```

Xargs runs "svn co (path-in-url)" for each white-space delimited word discovered by svn list and grep.  (The weird -I'{}' is necessary otherwise xargs puts a space between the URL and the subdirectory name.)